# Extending existing activity designers

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I am looking to create a custom activity which is essentially the same as the 'If' activity but would like to add an extra button to the designer (just above the Condition expression text box). Does anyone know if this is even possible or would I have to create a brand new custom activity (along with a new designer) with all the same functionality as the 'If' one but with my extra bits added?

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you are rehosting the designer or want to use the functionality in VS. With a rehosted desogner there are several ways to update the UI of existing activities like using [WPF adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)

See [Visual Workflow Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624139.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Oh, not heard of that before! I should have stated that it is a solution rehosting a designer. I shall have a look at this. Thank you very much for the reply.